# JS - Radio buttons with images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hate being a noob in a coding world....I'm going out to walk the dog and asking for some help in the meantime.

I have five images going to be used as a button "up" states, as well as five images used as their "down" states.  All I want to do is when one button is clicked, all images change back to their up states, and the one I chose goes to the down-state.  Simple right.  I'm getting lost when I am trying to access the image name and then have it switch with the down image.  I got this working but I used two huge switch statements inside an if statement.  Way too long and I know I can do it better.

Can someone point me in the right direction? You can even give me hints to make me figure it out for myself and make me stronger :)

Thanks

```js
var pathStr = "images/lessons/lessonBtns/";
var btnArray = ["kBtn", "firstBtn", "secondBtn", "thirdBtn", "fourthBtn"];

function toggleGradeBtns(gradeBtn) {
  var gradeBtnArray = document.getElementsByClassName("grade-btn");
  console.log(gradeBtnArray);

  for (var i = 0; i < gradeBtnArray.length; i++) {
    gradeBtnArray[i].children[0].src = "images/lessons/lessonBtns/" + btnArray[i] + ".png";
    gradeBtnArray[i].dataset.checked = 0;
  }

  if (gradeBtn.dataset.checked == 0) {
    gradeBtn.dataset.checked = 1;
    console.log(gradeBtn.children[0].src);
    switch (gradeBtn.children[0].src) {
      case pathStr + "kBtn.png":
        gradeBtn.children[0].src = pathStr + "kBtnDown.png";
        break;

      case pathStr + "firstBtn.png":
        gradeBtn.children[0].src = pathStr + "firstBtnDown.png";
        break;

      case pathStr + "secondBtn.png":
        gradeBtn.children[0].src = pathStr + "secondBtnDown.png";
        break;

      case pathStr + "thirdBtn.png":
        gradeBtn.children[0].src = pathStr + "thirdBtnDown.png";
        break;

      case pathStr + "fourthBtn.png":
        gradeBtn.children[0].src = pathStr + "fourthBtnDown.png";
        break;
    }
  } else {
    gradeBtn.dataset.checked = 0;
    switch (gradeBtn.children[0].src) {
      case pathStr + "kBtn.png":
        gradeBtn.children[0].src = pathStr + "kBtn.png";
        break;

      case pathStr + "firstBtn.png":
        gradeBtn.children[0].src = pathStr + "firstBtn.png";
        break;

      case pathStr + "secondBtn.png":
        gradeBtn.children[0].src = pathStr + "secondBtn.png";
        break;

      case pathStr + "thirdBtn.png":
        gradeBtn.children[0].src = pathStr + "thirdBtn.png";
        break;

      case pathStr + "fourthBtn.png":
        gradeBtn.children[0].src = pathStr + "fourthBtn.png";
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed lots of useless JavaScript and changed how the clicked button is activated. *I also removed `console.log` for conciseness*.

```
var pathStr = "images/lessons/lessonBtns/";
var btnArray = ["kBtn", "firstBtn", "secondBtn", "thirdBtn", "fourthBtn"];

function toggleGradeBtns(gradeBtn) {
  var gradeBtnArray = document.getElementsByClassName("grade-btn");

  for (var i = 0; i < gradeBtnArray.length; i++) {
    gradeBtnArray[i].children[0].src = pathStr + btnArray[i] + ".png";
  }

  gradeBtn.children[0].src = gradeBtn.children[0].src.slice(0, -4) + "Down.png";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just HTML and CSS.  Of course, you can do it with JS, too, but I love the simplicity:

```css
#image::after {
    content: "";
    font-size: 200px;
}

#checkButton:checked ~ #image::after {
    content: "";
}

#checkButton:checked ~ label {
background-color: black;
color: white;
}

#checkButton {
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
}

label {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkButton">

<label for="checkButton"> label that looks like a button </label>    

<div id="image"></div>
```

For more on this "method", Google "css checkbox hack."

Also, I've used emoji for simplicity here, but you could just as well use `content: url('your-url-here')`.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried to mess around with this method and found a video on youtube as well.  Where would the original up state picture go?  is it the url content in the css file or do I need to plug it in on the html file?

Comment: @user2957919 The URLs would go in the CSS file after `content`.  The 2nd picture would go in the `[checked]` block.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my CSS/HTML-only approach to this. If you need each up and down arrow to be different, you can give each radio button an ID and style them individually.

```css
[type=radio] { 
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

[type=radio] + p {
  display: inline;
}

[type=radio] + p::after {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/111-1118943_up-arrow-icon-png-up-arrow-symbol-png.png);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px; 
  height: 20px;
  content:"";
}

[type=radio]:checked + p::after {
  background-image: url(https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/down-xxl.png);
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px; 
  height: 20px;
  content:"";
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="1" checked> <p></p>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="2"> <p></p>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="3"> <p></p>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="4"> <p></p>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="4"> <p></p>
</label>
```